# scp hangs on SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

Tags: ssh, scp

I frequently scp my file to remote host. But suddenly it started taking more than 30 seconds to copy 20kb file.It used to take not more than half a second.
After referring to some blog I appended

`UseDNS no` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` .

But now while I scp it gives

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 61: Bad configuration option: UseDNS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UseDNS no` should be on the *server*'s `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (not *ssh*_config). It has no meaning in `ssh_config`.

Answer (score 0):

did you check your name servers ? Did the one or two DNS resolvers on top of the /etc/resolv.conf file is/are inaccessible for some reason ?

```
grep ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf
```

try to ping the IP addresses of the nameservers. Most probably the top one is not going to respond, for which you are waiting for 30 seconds to timeout. Hence your 30 seconds delay. If you are the server admin, i.e., have root access, either delete this nameserver or push it down to become lower importance.

Answer (score 0):

This had no effect for me until I realized I had to restart the ssh daemon, after guessing the meaning of the 'd'.

```
service sshd restart
```

While this got rid of the 10-second hang at this point in my scp, I am still getting the broken pipe/lost connection which had prompted me to run scp in verbose mode in the first place. Back to the old drawing board..